# app not getting downloaded in some android device from play store

Tags: android, google-play, android-resolution

I have made and app and published in play store. I have also made the layout for sw600dp (tablet 7") , but in some device like LENEVO K3 note and AMAZON OnePlus one its not getting downloaded. Both are 5.5inch device.
Please suggest me what may be the issue.

manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<!--
```

The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!--no small size screens -->


    <!--all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />

</compatible-screens>



<application
    android:name=".Application.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.StartUpScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.Login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Activity.StartActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.Signup"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_signup"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Activity.StartActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.Home"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".Search" />

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Activity.Search"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing|adjustPan"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.Brands"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        android:label="@string/title_activity_brands">

    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="api_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.Stores"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_stores"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.ProductRow"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.ProductDetails"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.UserProfile"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_user_profile"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.Filter"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_filter"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Activity.StartUpScreen" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.BrandsGrid"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_brands_grid"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.StartActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_start"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.ProductStoreCollections"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_product_collections"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: can you post your manifest.xml?

Comment: @GaurawYadav i have posted the manifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing [compatible-screen](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) from your AndroidManifest.

> The Android system does not read the  manifest
>   element (neither at install-time nor at runtime). This element is
>   informational only and may be used by external services (such as
>   Google Play) to better understand the application's compatibility with
>   specific screen configurations and enable filtering for users. Any
>   screen configuration that is not declared in this element is a screen
>   with which the application is not compatible. Thus, external services
>   (such as Google Play) should not provide the application to devices
>   with such screens.